# How do I Capture native (Menu) button presses in PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

By calling `BackButton.override();` and then hooking on to the `backKeyDown` event, I am able to get the back button press to register.

But there doesn't appear to be a `MenuButton.override();` Also, hooking on the `menuKeyDown` doesn't register a button press.

Here's my (non-functional) code. What am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>      

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {

            alert('initialized');
    }, false);
    document.addEventListener("menuKeyDown", function() {

            alert('menu_pressed'); // Never happens
    }, false);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of phongap.js does not support overriding menu key
for this edit you copy add the following code:

```
KeyEvent.prototype.menuTrigger = function()
{
  var e = document.createEvent('Events');
  e.initEvent('menuKeyDown');
  document.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, it worked great! I added it in the deviceready callback, and moved the addEventListener for menuKeyDown to the deviceready callback just after it.